# trying to parse Json but couldn't getting output,

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonparser

**input**
guys as you can see i am trying to parse json but couldn't getting a proper output.so please help me to figure out why am i getting this type of error

```
import json
data='''{'name':'shashank',
phone:{'type':'int1',
'number':'+3872847239474'}
'email':{
'hide':'yes'}
}'''
info=json.loads("data")
print('name:',info["name"])
print('hide:',info["email"]["hide"])
```

**output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-27b5f61ad286> in <module>
      6 'hide':'yes'}
      7 }'''
----> 8 info=json.loads("data")
      9 print('name:',info["name"])
     10 print('hide:',info["email"]["hide"])

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues. The JSON isn't formatted correctly (you need double quotes instead of single, you're missing a few commas, etc.) and when you call `json.loads`, you're passing in the *string* `'data'` instead of the variable `data`. This code works:

```py
import json
data='''{
    "name":"shashank",
    "phone":{
        "type":"int1",
        "number":"+3872847239474"
    },
    "email":{
        "hide":"yes"
    }
}'''
info=json.loads(data)
print('name:',info["name"])
print('hide:',info["email"]["hide"])
```